# Angular if condition from html to component?

Tags: html, angularjs, string, filter, components

I have this problem being very new in Angular : I want to make multiple filters in a table. So in order to achieve this, I want to make a "if" condition on the input, for example if I have a table head named "Entity" then it will tell my component class that it's the input Entity.

how do I Achieve this ?

```js
  public performFilter(filterBy: string): IDonnee[] {
      filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
      // I'd want to put the condition here like (if input.class == "entity then.."
      if (this.isFiltered) {
        return this.filteredDonnees.filter((donnee: IDonnee) =>
          donnee.entity.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
      } else {
          return this.donnees.filter((donnee: IDonnee) =>
            donnee.entity.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
        }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table *ngIf="donnees && donnees.length">
  <th>
    Entity
    <br>
    <input size={{thSize}} ng-model="entity" class="entity"[(ngModel)]="listFilter">
  </th>
  <th>
    bdrID
    <br>
    <input size={{thSize}} ng-model="bdrId" class="bdrId" [(ngModel)]="listFilter2">
  </th>
</table>
```

For example I'd like to get the class name of the input in my JS code.

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear u can ask any question and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, your aim is to filter when you click on the respective TH element? Like, call a click event on the Input element?

If that is the case, you could try something like this:
Provide an Id to the input elements:
    input id="donnees" (click)="performFilter($event)"
Similarly for both the TH elements.
For some weird reason, it is not letting me paste the full table code.

Instead of having multiple arrays, I think it is better to have a single object with all the arrays, so that you can filter based on the ID passed from $event.
Eg: filterObject => donnees[], filteredDonnees[]

```
public performFilter(event) {
  return this.filterObject[event.target.Id].filter(// write your condition here);
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hello, so I have in this example 2 columns, then when I write something in the input (which is just under) of the first column, it will filter it, then when I write something in the second input, it will filter what is left of the data after it's filtered with the first input. (sorry if it's hard to understand!)

I will try your method and come back in a second (adjusting it for my code) thanks!

So I didn't really use an event, just added the filter right onto the component each time a key is pressed and the filter string is changed

Comment: in ur example, how would I access the id of the input without having the event?

Comment: The event will be (keyup)='performFilter($event)' and not click.

Comment: Okay i'm going to try that, I'm trying to understand the logic behind this. What is filterObject for ? I mean what is filterObject[event.target.id] does that mean it's an array for example of entities if the id = entity ?

Comment: Instead of having multiple items, its better if you have one object so that you can filter by passing in the id. That is just for better readability and code management. Lets say, if you have one more array in the future, you will have to add one more 'If' condition for that array. But if you follow this method, your performFilter object always remains the same. If you do not want to do that way, you can still use the method you have, where you can use the Id in the if condition and do the same as you have. filterObject[event.target.id] => if Id is donnees it will filter the object donnees

Comment: Any luck? @Mich

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution but I can't seem to make it. With my solution, how would I get the "id" of the input ? since it's not with an event I can't use event.target.Id, i've also tried let searchId = element(by.model('entity')); but it doesn't work =/ it seems so simple but I can't seem to make it.

Comment: thanks for your help i'll try again tomorrow, have a nice day ! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182731/discussion-between-minu-and-mich).

Comment: Try this sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pp762f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts